# Pull GitHub repo on Ubuntu server start

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, git

I have an autoscaling EC2 group and I have a central config using git between servers. They are set up with keys, so they don't need a password.

I want to make sure when an instance gets started and created from the AMI (with a possibly outdated config) that it pulls the config using a normal git pull command. The command has to be executed as a certain user as only that user can git pull as it's the one with the RSA key in it's home directory.

So essentially on server start a certain user needs to run git pull in a certain repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that command in /etc/rc.local. Modify rc.local in your image, so that it consists of something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

pushd /certain/repository
su -s /bin/bash -c "git pull" <username>
popd
exit 0
```

Just replace  with the user under which privileges you want 'git pull' to be run.
Also, just in case, don't forget to run:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

This is the part from relevant RedHat documentation on rc.local, but it's basically the same on all distros:

> The /etc/rc.d/rc.local script is executed by the init command at boot time or when changing runlevels. Adding commands to the bottom of this script is an easy way to perform necessary tasks like starting special services or initialize devices without writing complex initialization scripts in the /etc/rc.d/init.d/ directory and creating symbolic links.

Comment: Well that executes as root, right? Would that not mess up permission for things like gits HEAD file etc? Is there a way to run the command as a different user?

Comment: I modified my answer to accommodate your concerns.